# Gulp - remove comments from javascript files

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm looking for a way to remove all comments from a javascript file using gulp.

for example, I have the following code:

```
/***
 * Comment 1 - This is my javascript header
 * @desc comment header to be removed
 * @params req, res
 */

(function() {
    var helloworld = 'Hello World'; // Comment 2 - this is variable
    /* Comment 3 - this is the printing */
    console.log(helloworld);
})()
```

And my expected result is:

```
(function() {
    var helloworld = 'Hello World';
    console.log(helloworld);
})();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want remove just comments, you can use [gulp-strip-comments](https://github.com/RnbWd/gulp-strip-comments)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var strip = require('gulp-strip-comments');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('template.js')
    .pipe(strip())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

If you want also minify a file, use [uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify)

Comment: What do you mean by "just comments" can it's output be piped to uglify/minify?

Comment: Silly me, I had a preserveComments on the uglify config to save some of the comments. Thanks